# C# - Erro após mudar de 32 para 64bits

Tags: c#

Meu projeto estava compilando normal, mas quando mudei de 32 para 64 apareceu um monte de erros. Se ignoro e continuo vários componentes somem. Sou novo em C#. tem como eu restaurar o projeto para um dia anterior como fazia em Delphi? Segue a imagem.

Obrigado[image: Erro que está a dar]

Answer (score 5):

Você desenvolveu os seus componentes em um projeto (class Library) separado? Se sim, as bibliotecas devem ser colocadas como AnyCPU, somente os executáveis devem ser compilados como 32 ou 64 bits.

Se não tiver colocado os componentes em uma biblioteca separada, crie um novo projeto Class Library, incorpore os seus componentes nele e defina o método de compilação como AnyCPU.

Para alterar a configuração acesse a opção Build -> Configuration Manager.
[image: Menu Configuration Manager]

A configuração deve ficar como esta descrito abaixo:
[image: Configuração x86]
[image: Configuração x64]

Comment: Valeu pela informação e funcionou, mas agora o form aparece sem dois componentes ListwiewEx. Compila sem erro. Tem como fazer os componentes aparecerem novamente?

Comment: Isso é um bug comum do Visual Studio, quando você abriu a aplicação que não apareceram os componentes o Visual Studio deve ter apresentado uma mensagem indicando que iria remover os componente inválidos, ao clicar em yes o visual studio mudou o seu arquivo .designer.cs removendo os componentes que ele considerava inválidos, provavelmente você salvou o o arquivo e perdeu a informação, agora só refazendo ou restaurando a partir do controle de versões.

Comment: @pleonardomv, se a pergunta tiver lhe ajudado, aceite a resposta por favor